# Rails: Param problems with delete button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, parameters, destroy

index.html:

```
  <% @partners.each do |j| %>
            <% if j.link == nil %>
                <div class="column_left"><%= j.name %></div>
            <% else %> 
                <div class="column_left"><%= image_tag("#{j.link}") %></div>
            <% end %>
            <div class="column_right"><%= j.description %></div>
            <%if logged_in? %>
                <%= button_to "-", j, :method => :destroy , data: { confirm: "Sind Sie sich sicher, dass sie den Partner #{j.name} löschen wollen?" } %>
            <% end %>
```

controller:

```
    def delete
        Partner.find(partner_params).destroy_all
        redirect_to partner_path, notice: "#Eintrag wurde gelöscht!"
    end

    def addPartner
        @partner = Partner.new(partner_params)
        if !Partner.exists?(:name => partner_params[:name])
            uploaded_io = params[:partner][:logo]
            File.open(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'partner', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
              file.write(uploaded_io.read)
            @partner[:link] = "partner/#{uploaded_io.original_filename}"
            params[:partner].delete :logo
            @partner.save
            redirect_to partner_path, notice: "#{@partner.name} wurde modifiziert!"

            end
        else
          @partner = Partner.where(:name => partner_params[:name])
          if @partner.update_all(partner_params)
            flash[:notice] = "#{@partner.name} wurde geändert!"
          end
        end
      end

    private
       def partner_params
          params.require(:partner).permit(:name, :link, :description)
       end
```

routes.rb:

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  get '/home' => 'main#home'
  get '/impressum' => 'main#impressum'
  post '/impressum' => 'main#updateImpressumById'
  get '/partner' => 'partner#index'
  post '/partner' => 'partner#addPartner'
  delete '/partner' => 'partner#delete'
  get '/jobs' => 'jobs#index'
  post '/jobs' => 'jobs#index'
  get '/kontakt' => 'contacts#new'
  post '/home' => 'main#updateText'
  get '/referenzen' => 'reference#index'
  post '/referenzen' => 'reference#index'

  resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]
```

I want to delete an entry from my database by clicking on a button. But there must be a conflict with the "private_params".
I always got this problem:

param is missing or the value is empty: partner

I searched for similiar problems, but nothing seems to fit really.

Comment: Try like this example `<%= button_to "Delete Image", { action: "delete", id: @image.id }, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>` [DOCS](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help Gabbar, but now I found the solution on my own. Was a pretty stupid one. 
I called

```
method: destroy
```

but it must be:  `method: delete`
otherwise the wrong path is chosen.

Then the routes.rb need to be:  `delete '/partner' => 'partner#delete'`

Comment: hmm you didn't see my answer, i also used method: delete, and i asked you also if are you using the given solution .? anyway i have corrected the routes and controller for you, hope it helped you. feel free to upvote answer or accept. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete an entry then you need to send a `id` of partner

```
        <%if logged_in? %>
          <%= button_to "Delete", partner_path(id: j.id), :method => :delete %>
        <% end %>
```

Controller: -

```
def destroy
    Partner.find(params[:id]).destroy_all
    redirect_to partner_path, notice: "#Eintrag wurde gelöscht!"
end
```

Routes: -

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  get '/home' => 'main#home'
  get '/impressum' => 'main#impressum'
  post '/impressum' => 'main#updateImpressumById'
  get '/partners' => 'partner#index'
  post '/partners' => 'partner#addPartner'
  delete '/partner/:id' => 'partner#delete'
  get '/jobs' => 'jobs#index'
  post '/jobs' => 'jobs#index'
  get '/kontakt' => 'contacts#new'
  post '/home' => 'main#updateText'
  get '/referenzen' => 'reference#index'
  post '/referenzen' => 'reference#index'

  resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]
```

Comment: First of all: Thanks for the help, but I still got the same error.

Comment: did it resolve your issue?, feel free to accept answer or upvote it.

Comment: one more thing , instead of `partner_path(id: j.id)` you need to pass your own path for destroy action.

Comment: yeah, did that. but didn't fix the problem.

Comment: whats the problem? can you explain it in comments.

Comment: It seems that there must be a collision with the partner_params.

Comment: if your purpose is to delete one partner than you need to send his id to destroy controller

Comment: Hm. I try to explain it more. I got the Error: ActionController::ParameterMissing in PartnerController#addPartner
param is missing or the value is empty: partner
and it return the line where i defined the partner_params

But it happens when i click on the delete button.

Comment: can you post you `routes.rb` file

Comment: Edited main entry

Comment: please have a look at `routes` file, i made some changes for partners controller

Comment: its best practice to follow REST ful routes.

Comment: Still no changes.

Comment: is it same error? are you using the given solution .?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want delete 1 record, use the method `destroy` like this :

```
Partner.find(params[:id]).destroy
```

Now, if you want delete more than 1, use `destroy_all` passing a condition as an argument, like this :

```
 Partner.destroy_all(status: 'inactive')
```

So, replace destroy_all with destroyer, like this:

```
Partner.find(params[:id]).destroy
```

I hope that helps you

[Destroy_all documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all)